# C# send AT Command using Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, at-command

I am able to send sms when my phone is connected via Cable, but when i am sending via Bluetooth it throw exception "No Phone Connected", My mobile is paired and it shows Bluetooth COMPORT is 15, I changed port number to 15 in my C# code it doesn't work.

can you please tell me how to send SMS using Bluetooth via AT Command OR using Comm library ?

Comment: Would be great to know your phone model and how do you send SMS? Do you use any library or?

Comment: "Yes I am using CommLibrary, I am using Samsung Grand Prime this work perfect for me. but only if Cable is connected."

Comment: Which service do you connect to? If it is SPP service then as far as I remember Android 5 does not support SMS on this service. You have to use MAP service instead.

Comment: I am using this software

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem-2

Comment: It does not matter. device may act as GSM modem when connected by USB/Serial interface. But Bluetooth works a bit different. It provides some "services" which do different functions. For SMS sending Android provides MAP profile (service). It is OBEX based service (so it will not understand AT commands). To be able to send SMS you have to connect to MAP service and use its commands (refer to OBEX first) work with SMS.

Comment: I think i am getting your point. Okay How to connect MAP service, I am not familiar with MAP service, where should i start?

Comment: First you should use any way to connect to Bluetooth directly without COM ports (becasue windows will not create vCOM for MAP service). Next you have to learn MAP profile specification (easy to find in google). Next: basic OBEX communication. I guess there should be some code that already implements it. But any way, you have to get direct Bluetooth connection (when you can specify which service you want to connect to(,

Comment: Let me try, i will get back to you soon thanks